# Static files in django when extending from template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

So i am having trouble loading my static files (images) in my template when extending from my base.html, so in my base.html the static files are working for example my favicon and my style are all loading. But when i want to load an image in my charts.html it does not work.
To be clear the problem lies with the `barchart_coins.png` file.

This is my charts.html file

```
{% extends "main/base.html" %}
{% load  static %}
{% block title %}Charts{% endblock %}
{% block subtitle %}<h1 class="h1">Welcome to your crypto wallet visualized</h1>{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
   <img type="image/png" src"{% static "images/barchart_coins.png" %}" alt="barchart">
{% endblock %}
```

This is my base.html file

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">            
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/css/style.css' %}">
    <title>
        {% block title %}<h1>You forgot to place a title in your file<h1>{% endblock %}
    </title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'main/images/bitcoin_fav.png' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/overview">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="/data">General data</a></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="body">
    {% block subtitle %}<h2>>ou forgot to place a subtitle in your file<h2>{% endblock %}
    {% block form %}<p>You forgot to place a fom in your file</p>{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
    <p>You forgot to place a content in your file</p>
    {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is part of my settings.py file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/main'),
)
```

my file structure looks like the following

```
crypto_api_site
    >bitvavo_api
    >crypto_api_site
        >settings.py
    >main
        >static
             >main
                 >images
                      >barchart_coins.png
        >templates
             >main
                 >base.html
                 >charts.html
```

I hope I gave all the necesary files and I look forward to everybody suggestions.

Comment: What does `barchart`'s **src** attribute look like when you inspect the field in the developer console?- and if you open up the Network pane in developer console + refresh, it'll show you all the URLs it tries to ping.. those two things could help narrow down the problem

Comment: @Nealium I just made it work, I have not really found out what the problem was but thanks for your speedy reply and your help was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be the single quotes, not double on the inside of the static file: src"{% static 'images/barchart_coins.png' %}"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a little misunderstanding and mix of concepts. There are two options to collect static files from different folders into `STATIC_ROOT`:

- `STATICFILES_DIRS`
- and `static` subfolder within each app folder with [STATICFILES_FINDERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders) enabled

In your config `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/main')` actually points to the `crypto_api_site/static/main` which does not exist. But `AppDirectoriesFinder` if it is enabled should catch folder `main/static` however after running `collectstatic` it would result in `<STATIC_ROOT>/<APP_NAME>/<PATH_TO_FILE_AFTER_APP/STATIC>` e.g. `crypto_api_site/static_files/main/images/barchart_coins.png`

thus
`{% static 'main/images/bitcoin_fav.png' %}`
would work because `AppDirectoriesFinder` will go to `main/static` and find there this relative path `main/images/bitcoin_fav.png`

however
`{% static "images/barchart_coins.png" %}` will not work because there is no such file meeting `[<STATIC_ROOT>|<app/static>]/images/barchart_coins.png` path. If your template is in the `main` app - this not the reason to shorten static file url/path.

Finally:

- define `STATIC_ROOT` folder explicitly
- run `collectstatic` to see where it will go to find your static files and what folder structure it will produce
- adjust your static file referencing in templates